# How to show combobox before page load in javascript or PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, combobox

My client wants, when customer loges in, he should be prompted to select a page (i.e admin or  home) where he will be redirected, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should use something like: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ and ask the user while she on your page what is the next page (admin/home).

Answer (score 0):

If loggin successfully ,you can trigger a popup like something having some options for admin,home ,just links would be great

sample http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

You may call a popup page with the combobox in it on load of the Login Page.
Demo : http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

The page which he logs in make it as a selector dummy page.

means the page does nothing but display of combobox and handle the redirect.

login.php->redirect.php->admin.php or home.php

you can either do this by spiting up the entire page section with a php request method.

Or you can give a option where the user can select the page form the login panel it self in that way you can easily do the page redirection.